# Declaring variable in function call

Tags: c++, c

My struct:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    Point(int nX, int nY) { x = nX; y = nY; }
    Point() {};
};
```

Function:

```
void functionName(Point target);
```

And I want declare variable in function call: (pseudocode)

```
functionName(Point variable(5,0));
```

I'm writing in C or C++.

Comment: You cannot do that in neither language. For what would you need that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you meant to construct a temporary `Point` and pass it to the function, you could (for C++):

```
functionName(Point(5,0));
```

Or for C++11:

```
functionName(Point{5,0});
```

Answer (score 2):

[For C, ignoring the c'tor and d'tor]

```
struct Point {
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

Use a compound literal like this:

```
functionName((struct Point){5, 0});
```

Please not that the compound literal defined by this lives on the stack of the current context until the context is left.

To have it be deallocated immediately the function return, wrap the function call in its own context by doing:

```
{
  functionName((struct Point){5, 0});
}
```

Comment: A bit unrelated, but Is that last point about compound literals also valid for other types of variables? Can you also access them (reliably) while they're still on the stack?

Comment: @ToVine: Yes, sure.

Comment: How do you get the references/pointers to them then? (it's obviously not how I think one should go about it if knowing in advance that the variable is needed outside that specific function call, I'm just curious)

Comment: @ToVine: I  was inaccurate when answering "Yes" to your question whether it would be accessible. So: It would be valid to access it, if you'd had the chance to refer to it, which you haven't, as it's unnamed in the calling context ... :}

Comment: Still you could do `{ struct Point * pp;
  functionName(*(pp = &(struct Point){5, 0})); ...` and then refer to it ("*relibaly*") doing `pp->x` for example.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use that variable, after the function finishes (I think you might as well do, since you want to give your argument a name), you would probably want to pass ref/pointer, for example :

```
void functionName(Point& target);
Point variable(5,0);
functionName(variable);
```

In case you dont really need the variable, you can simply pass an rvalue, by calling the constructor as argument :

```
functionName(Point(5,0));
```

notice that the 'target' will be destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: "*... notice that the 'target' will be destroyed when the function returns*" which would be (slightly) different ins C.